# Error after trying to upgrade fully to Cosmic on Kubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu

I'm on the command line (ssh'd into my box) which at one point was running the previous version of Kubuntu.  I ran the do-release-upgrade command to get the latest and greatest version.
However I think something failed because after reboot, I don't have all the updates installed.

I'm prompted to do a apt --fix-broken install from the command line and receive the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../breeze_4%3a5.13.5-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking breeze (4:5.13.5-0ubuntu2) over (4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/breeze_4%3a5.13.5-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/org.kde.breezedark.desktop.appdata.xml', which is also in package plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/breeze_4%3a5.13.5-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: So sadly the duplicate doesn't work fully since there are so many dependencies on the plasma portions which I can't remove unless I find the top level dependency? Since plasma is core, I would have to remove all of the plasma-* plus the breezy-*